# Is there any book discussing geometry through differential forms?

Tags: differential-forms

I am searching for a book on differential forms which deals with doing plane geometry problems through forms. For instance, in beginning linear algebra, there are questions of finding equation of line and planes. These questions can also be done through differential forms. For example:

If we have a one form $a$, then if we consider the one form corresponding to the dual of the position vector of a point on the line $c$, we have the equation of line as:

$$ a \wedge c=0$$

Similarly equations can be done for lines.

Forms also allow us to treat area as a vector (in the sense of adding oriented planes). This can for instance, make questions such as finding the plane having the intersect line of two planes intersecting at an angle and perpendicular to one of them easy.

I am supposing one could solve geometrically problems using this aspect of differential forms. However, I have no book which does this. Could something be recommended?

Comment: Your profile picture makes me hungry.

Comment: It is one of the few good things I find every time I go to India 

Comment: A Riemannian metric is usually written as $ds^2= \sum_{ij}g_{ij} dx_i\otimes dx_j$ where $dx_i,dx_j$ are differential forms. I know hardly any DG book that does not mention this.

Comment: I am confused, how does that relate to what I asked @KurtG.?

Comment: "geometry through differential forms"

Comment: Well yeah, sort of, but I mean geometry in a different sense. I am trying to find a book which deals with those basic linear algebra problems one found in geometry  but done in a differential form perspective.

Comment: For instance, if we have two one forms $a,b$ if a third vector $c$ is in the plane spanned by the vector dual of em, then $a \wedge b \wedge c = 0$

Comment: You may want to formalize this question a bit. The distance from point to plane can be claculated with some Riemannian metric for sure.

Comment: Maybe a book discussing geometric algebra is something in that direction.

Comment: I tried my best to modify it @KurtG.

Comment: Such expressions appear a lot in Geometric Algebra books. There is a Wikipedia article that should get you started.

Comment: Hmm I sort of knew what that was, I was trying to find a book wihch went without talking about grassman product and did geoemtry but I suppose that doesn't exist

Comment: I don't know. Grothendieck used to say "we don't read books we write them ourselves".

Comment: Is [Fortney - A visual introduction to differential forms and calculus on manifolds](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-96992-3) in the spirit that you want?

Comment: I didn't read the whole book but I did check a part of it when I was beginning. It seemed so more about calculus with forms as well. If you have a page number on where the things I said are discussed then I'll check that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differential forms are really not the point. You want to work with the dual space and exterior product of vectors in a fixed vector space. I recommend you look at Dan Pedoe's *Geometry: A Comprehensive Course*. It has beautiful material (including classical results in projective geometry and the use of Grassmannians) and introduces exterior product of vectors very early on.

Comment: Are differential forms something beyond the dual space?

Comment: Yes, even in a vector space, they have coefficient functions and one differentiates and integrates them. In this setting the exterior algebra is purely static.

Comment: My doubt is , if they have such more structure, shouldn't they be more useful? Why is it that these properties are removed before doing geometry in the conventional sense?

Comment: I’m not going to debate with you. I have spent a career using and teaching differential forms in differential and algebraic geometry. You should start by rewriting your post so that it actually makes sense. How is $a\wedge c$ an equation? And please write up the “easy” application you have in mind in the next paragraph. When you make this all meaningful, you will see that you’re using the exterior algebra, but, I believe, none of the interesting structure of differential forms. Perhaps when you write it carefully and clearly you’ll prove me wrong.

Comment: I actually did not mean it as criticism, I genuinely do not get it. I will fix the post on the points you said

Answer (score 0):

Differential Geometry and Forms by Needham might be what you want.

Comment: mmmm I'm almost done reading that book. That book's presentation of forms is more about doing calculus (eg: calculating curvature and such) with it than geometry in the traditional sense/ sense I mentioned in post